# How to get IMSI on Nokia phones using J2ME

Tags: java, java-me

I am trying to the get the [IMSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Subscriber_Identity) using `System.getProperty("com.nokia.mid.imsi"));` But it keeps returning me a null value.

I have tried this on N97 mini and E71 which runs on Symbian OS.

Is it my code error or some settings that I need to do to get the IMSI??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could access "com.nokia.mid.imsi" System property on S60 3rd Edition FP2 , but only having manufacturer/operator domain permissions so, there is no practical way to get it.because

If you want to sign your app with an operator/manufacturer certificate it won't be that easy. You'll have to contact them about that.

Answer (score 0):

you can even try adding "com.nokia.mid.mobinfo.IMSI" permission to application descriptor file.